# Move textfield above keypad

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, scrollview

I have been implementing this code given in the documentation for pushing UIViews like textfields above the keyboard to make it visible - I understand and successfully implement the code but I am just confused about some lines in a particular function. Can anyone please explain me that? I have commented views of mine about the coding . If I am wrong please rectify me?

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification)
    {
        //Need to calculate keyboard exact size due to Apple suggestions
        self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true//enable the scrol view
        let info : NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!//get the userinfo for height of the keyboard
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().size//get the keyboard height
        let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)

        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets//adjusts the bottom content inset of the scroll view by the height of the keyboard , contentInset - The distance that the content view is inset from the enclosing scroll view.

        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets//scrollIndicatorInsets - The distance the scroll indicators are inset from the edge of the scroll view.

        var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
        aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
        if let activeFieldPresent = activeField//check for the textfield that is active
        {
            if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField!.frame.origin))
            {
                self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField!.frame, animated: true)
            }
        }


    }
```

Now my question is what is going on in this part of the code -

```
var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
            aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
            if let activeFieldPresent = activeField//check for the textfield that is active
            {
                if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField!.frame.origin))
                {
                    self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField!.frame, animated: true)
                }
            }
```

Please explain a bit line-wise. Thanks I would be very helpful by your answers.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Stop adding the language tag to the title. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303606/is-it-ok-to-systematically-edit-the-questions-titles-like-this

Comment: @EricD.-- tax for your valueable information , i future I follow this